# Collapse a dataframes column into its distinct values and create a new column based on anothers frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take a dataframe such as:

```
    USER    PACKAGE
0   1       1
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   1       1
4   1       2
5   1       3
6   2       ...
```

And select the distinct USERS and then have new columns that are based on the frequency of the different packages. i.e highest frequency package, second highest etc.

```
    User  First   Second    Third
0   1     1       2         3
1   2     ...
```

I can implement this with for loops but thats obviously bad using dataframes, I need to run this on millions of records, can't quite find a vectorized way of doing it.

Cheers

Comment: The data shown is a bad example since  the result for 'First' happens to be 1, 'Second' happens to be 2 and 'Third' 3. So that won't stress the need to sort the output then take top-3.

Comment: On SO you're supposed to **attempt the question and post your own code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with default sorting, so get first 3 index values, convert to `Series`, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), `rename` columns and last convert index to column:

```
print (df)
   USER  PACKAGE
0     1        1
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     1        1
4     1        2
5     1        3
6     2        3


df = (df.groupby('USER')['PACKAGE']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().index[:3]))
        .unstack()
        .rename(columns= dict(enumerate(['First','Second','Third'])))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   USER  First  Second  Third
0     1    1.0     2.0    3.0
1     2    3.0     NaN    NaN
```

If need all counts:

```
df = (df.groupby('USER')['PACKAGE']
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().index))
        .unstack())
print (df)
        0    1    2
USER               
1     1.0  2.0  3.0
2     3.0  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT: Another idea, I hope faster is use:

```
s = (df.groupby('USER')['PACKAGE']
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[:3]))
        
df = (pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index, columns=['First','Second','Third'])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   USER  First  Second  Third
0     1      1     2.0    3.0
1     2      3     NaN    NaN
```

Comment: there are 3 item where user=1 and package=1.  For user 1 then first=3, second=2 and third=1.   I think your results are incorrect based on inspection of the original data.

Comment: @GoldenLion = OP need  - `And select the distinct USERS and then have new columns that are based on the frequency of the different packages. i.e highest frequency package, second highest etc.` And I understand it `First` is `1`, because 3 times is `1`, second is `2`, because 2 times 2 and ast is `3`, because 1 times `3`. Output is correct.

Comment: Ok  I added a comment about how to extract the rank below.   it is strange to mix rank with frequency.  this produces confusion.

Answer (score 2):

On SO you're supposed to attempt it and **post your own code**. Here are some hints for implementing the solution:

- Do `.groupby('USER')`... then `.value_counts()` ...
- (don't need to `.sort()`, since `.value_counts()` does that by default)
- take the [`.head(3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)...
- then `pivot` into a table, in that same pivot command there's an option to add the column names 'First, Second, Third'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28342649)

Comment: @gehbiszumeis please explain how groupby('user').value_counts() followed by sort_values().top(3) followed by df.pivot_table(...) doesn't attempt to answer the question? I'd say an answer that exercises the user's mind while simultaneously answering a question that shows no visible effort is better than one that hands the answer on a silver spoon

Comment: @gehbiszumeis This **does** provide an answer to the question; it clearly identiifies which 5 pandas commands can be chained together. Your claim is false.

Comment: @smci (and cs95). I see both of your points. However, as you even write in your answer, you are giving hints (to something certainly providing an answer to the question), which I as a reviewer, however, see more appropriate as a comment rather than as posting it as an answer. Since the comment has already two upvotes, I seem not to be alone with this opinion. However, one can argue about the phrasing of the automated review comment, which I certainly wouldn't have spelled that way in this situation.

Comment: @jezrael: No it's not wrong. a) The `sort()` may be necessary (in general case) like I posted in comment 1 hour ago, since the OP's data example just happens to give results for 'First' happens to be 1, 'Second' happens to be 2 and 'Third' 3. So that won't stress the need to sort the output then take top-3. b) Obviously by `.top(3)` I meant to write `.head(3)`, you could have simply pointed that out constructively. It's not allowed to attack other answers.

Comment: @jezrael: As to still means an extra sort would only be 'superfluous' not 'wrong'; I wasn't aware [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) by default sorts by value. As to whether answerers are obligated to post the entire syntax of the answer when user didn't post any code attempt even when asked, as we've been flagging for an hour that seems like a [violation of the spirit of SO rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going/393454#393454)...

Comment: ..and by not having any code in the question, not even mentioning a command or two (groupby, value_counts, pivot), that makes this maddeningly hard to search and index, so that duplicates cannot be caught. Allowing questions with no code simply to pass **will ensure a stream of future duplicates**.

Comment: Anyway my answer is complete, please stop describing it as "wrong" or "incomplete answer" or "suggestion", those are all repeated violations of SO rules. Take this to Meta discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['X']).get_group('A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the count the number of user and package occurrences

```
USER =[1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
PACKAGE=[1,1,2,1,2,3,3]
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':USER,'package':PACKAGE})
results=df.groupby(['user','package']).size()
results=results.sort_values(ascending=False)
results=results.unstack(level='package').fillna(0)
results=results.rename(columns={1:'First',2:'Second',3:'Third'})
print(results)

output:
 package  First  Second  Third
 user                         
 1          3.0     2.0    1.0
 2          0.0     0.0    1.0
```

The highest frequency package is type 1, second highest package is type 2 and third highest package is type 3 for user 1.   the highest rank for user 2 is type 3.  You can do a lookup on the results to produce this output.